# No app icon preview in simulator dev menu - React Native Expo App

Tags: react-native, expo, ios-simulator

As the title explains I am working on a react native app using expo and have recently decided to create app icons and a splash screen for the app. I followed the tutorial from expo and used the provided figma template to create and export these images to use in my app. Following the tutorial I simply dragged the files into my /assets directory and replaced the existing images with the new ones. The splash screen works exactly as intended which makes me think everything is working fine with the way I imported the images and the file paths. My issue is that I cannot check to see if the icons are working because there is no preview of the app icon in the dev menu in my iOS simulator currently. I have been searching for a reason why this might be and have found nothing so far which is why I have resulted to asking if anybody else has had a similar issue and has found a solution.

Here is the code with the file paths for the images used for the icons and the splash screen just in case there is something I am messing up:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "frontend",
    "slug": "frontend",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#000000"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

and here is what the dev menu looks like in my simulator currently:

[image: dev menu is expo go on iOS simulator]

Are there any settings I need to mess with or is there another reason why there is no icon preview for my app?